# Match a date with the same character separating the values

Tags: python, regex

I have to find dates in multiple formats in a text.
I have some regex like this one:

```
# Detection of:
# 25/02/2014 or 25/02/14 or 25.02.14
regex = r'\b(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[-/\._](0?[1-9]|1[012])[-/\._]((?:19|20)\d\d|\d\d)\b'
```

The problem is that it also matches dates like `25.02/14` which is not good because the splitting character is not the same.

I could of course do multiple regex with a different splitting character for every regex, or do a post-treatment on the matching results, but I would prefer a complete solution using only one good regex. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: So basically just `\b\d{1,4}([./-])\d{1,4}\1\d{1,4}\b`?

Comment: What if you replace the separators before splitting uniformly to a dot (or slash)? `"25.02/14".replace("/", ".")`

Comment: @Rawing Yep, that did the trick.

Comment: Please post  **input** samples  and desired **output**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43548746/match-a-date-with-the-same-character-separating-the-values#comment74151236_43549315) (the original word boundary approach lets the pattern match "dates" that are in fact parts of other entities, like IPs, serial numbers, product IDs, etc.), see the improved version of your regex in comparison with yours:

```
import re

s = '25.02.19.35  6666-20-03-16-67875 25.02/2014 25.02/14 11/12/98 11/12/1998 14/12-2014 14-12-2014 14.12.1998'

found_dates = [m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'\b(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])([./-])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\1(?:19|20)?\d\d\b', s)]
print(found_dates) # initial regex

found_dates = [m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'(?<![\d.-])(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])([./-])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\1(?:19|20)?\d\d(?!\1\d)', s)]
print(found_dates) # fixed boundaries

# = >['25.02.19', '20-03-16', '11/12/98', '11/12/1998', '14-12-2014', '14.12.1998']
# => ['11/12/98', '11/12/1998', '14-12-2014', '14.12.1998']
```

See, your regex extracts `'25.02.19'` (part of a potential IP) and `'20-03-16'` (part of a potential serial number/product ID).

Note I also shortened the regex and extraction code a bit.

**Pattern details**:

- `(?<![\d.-])` - a negative lookbehind making sure there is no digit, `.`
   and `-` immediately to the left of the current location (`/` has been discarded since dates are often found inside URLs)
- `(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])` - `01` / `1` to `31` (day part)
- `([./-])` - Group 1 (technical group to hold the separator value) matching either `.`, or `/` or `-`
- `(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])` - month part: `01` / `1` to `12`
- `\1` - backreference to the Group 1 value to make sure the same separator comes here
- `(?:19|20)?\d\d` - year part: `19` or `20` (optional values) and then any two digits.
- `(?!\1\d)`  - negative lookahead making sure there is no separator (captured into Group 1) followed with any digit immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Your approach is useful, but it happens a lot that in a html, the date is in a url (like here): https://www.nytimes.com/2017/04/21/opinion/sunday/go-east-young-american.html?action=click&pgtype=Homepage&clickSource=story-heading&module=opinion-c-col-right-region&region=opinion-c-col-right-region&WT.nav=opinion-c-col-right-region
And in this case, the date is stuck between two slashes : `2017/04/21`.
Nota: sometimes this url appears in the html source code

Comment: Then remove `/` from the lookaheads.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment of Rawing, this did the trick:

```
regex = r'\b(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])([./-])(0?[1-9]|1[012])\2((?:19|20)\d\d|\d\d)\b'
```

So, the complete code is:

```
import re

s = '25.02/2014 25.02/14 11/12/98 11/12/1998 14/12-2014 14-12-2014 14.12.1998'

found_dates = []
for m in re.finditer(r'\b(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])([./-])(0?[1-9]|1[012])\2((?:19|20)\d\d|\d\d)\b', s):
    found_dates.append(m.group(0))
print(found_dates)
```

The output is, as desired :
`['11/12/98', '11/12/1998', '14-12-2014', '14.12.1998']`

Comment: See [what else this regex will match](https://regex101.com/r/5fKCMU/2). You might think of better word boundaries.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it can be that some unwanted strings are matched. But I'm using it on html source code and these cases seem pretty rare on this type of text, no ?

Comment: I mean that you may match a "date" that is in fact an IP. Or another entity type.